# Close current window when it call Open Tel:

Tags: javascript, tel

When I call window.location.href("tel:"+'+0060199999') it will open the Skype which is working fine.But i dont want current browser window stay open, i want to close it.If i put close, it is not even open the Skype.Is this possible to do?

```
  <html>

    <script>
    window.onload = function () {

    window.location.href="tel:+0060199999";
    window.close();
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    Let me test
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: *"it will open the Skype"* - Not on my computer.

Comment: [`location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) is not a method?!

Comment: window.location.href() ? did you mean window.open ?

Comment: it location.href , it can be replace with window.open("tel:"+'+0060199999','_self') but it still not working.I try both location.href and window.open

Comment: What good is a page that only tries to open a telephone application? Just link the `tel:` URI directly.

Comment: thank you for your reply. what do you mean link it directly? will it close the window that contains it right away after it open the skype?